# Which scripture describes Lord Shiva as īśaḿ (ईशं) ? Is it one of the form of Lord Shiva?

Tags: shiva, bhagavad-gita

While writing commentary on [Bhagavad Gita 11.15](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=11&field_nsutra_value=15&scsh=1&choose=1),

> paśyāmi devāḿs tava deva dehe
>   sarvāḿs tathā bhūta-viśeṣa-sańghān
>   brahmāṇam **īśaḿ** kamalāsana-stham
>   ṛṣīḿś ca sarvān uragāḿś ca divyān 
>   **Translation**: O God, I see assembled all the gods and various beings in your body, Lord Brahman, seated on a lotus seat, and all the dazzling Rsish and heavenly serpents.

But Vaishnava scholars translate ईशं (īśaḿ) as Shiva somehow. Which scripture(s) describe ईशं (īśaḿ) is Shiva? Or is it a form of Shiva? On what basis they put the word Shiva there?

Comment: Isha means lord which is one of the famous name of Shiva.  Like Mahesh Maha +Isha, Parameshwar = Parama + Ishwar. Girisham Ganesham Suresham Mahesham. All these words have Isha in them.

Comment: That is Isam. Not Isha. @Sarvabhouma

Comment: It is Isham. They are the same. Isham means who is Isha. rAmam means who is Rama. That is why you should proper transliteration. The word is Isham according to ITRANS ईशं in devanagari.

Comment: Most of the Scriptures call Shiva as Isha and Ishwara. Tantra also mostly calls as "Isha Uvaacha" or "Ishwara Uvaacha" when Shiva speaks. Usually Vishnu or his incarnations are called as "Bhagawaan or ShriBhagawaan" . I will try to find a proper verses , I remember reading them some where.

Comment: Btw, I've found that Ramanujacharya has also not used the word Shiva in [his commentary](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=11&field_nsutra_value=15&scram=1&choose=1)

Comment: @Pandya Isha is Shiva. I remember commenting on the same question. Are the comments deleted now?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Well, those discussion turned the shape of unfriendly debates and hence deleted. If you have an answer then write in the answer box.

Comment: Isha means Ichha/Aishwaraya(Aish/Ish+Varya, full of Iccha/desires) or who can fulfill his sons desires i.e you all. God has many faces Suresham(Vedic deites), Dinesham(Sun), Mahesham(Shiva), Vishvesham(Vishnu) etc.,

Answer (score 1):

In HariVamsha, Bhavisya Parva, 89th Chapter, 47th verse. Lord Siva refers to himself as Isa.

> Ka is a name of Brahma, and I (Siva) am known as Isa, because I am the
>   master of all living entities who reside in material bodies. Because
>   we are born from your body, you are therefore known as Kesava (the
>   father of Brahma and Siva)

ka iti brahmano nama
Iso 'ham sarva-dehinam
avam tavanga-sambhutau
tasmat kesava-nama-bhak